# Getting error message from cron job?

Tags: 12.04

PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library '/usr/lib/php5/20121212/pdo_mysql.so' - /usr/lib/php5/20121212/pdo_mysql.so: undefined symbol: pdo_parse_params in Unknown on line 0